# GLKit: [drawing pixels] initializing GLfloat array

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I am drawing a pixel using GLKit. I can successfully draw the pixel at (10, 10) coordinates if I have:

```
glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Prepare the effect for rendering 
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

GLfloat points[] =
{
    10.0f, 10.0f,
};

glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

GLuint bufferObjectNameArray;
glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObjectNameArray);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObjectNameArray);

glBufferData(
             GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             sizeof(points),
             points,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);

glVertexAttribPointer(
                      GLKVertexAttribPosition,
                      2,
                      GL_FLOAT,
                      GL_FALSE,
                      2*4,
                      NULL);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
```

But I want to decide at runtime how many and exactly where I want to draw pixels, so I tried this but it is drawing pixel at (10, 0), something's wrong here:

```
glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Prepare the effect for rendering 
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

GLfloat *points = (GLfloat*)malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * 2);
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    points[i] = 10.0f;
}

glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

GLuint bufferObjectNameArray;
glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObjectNameArray);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObjectNameArray);

glBufferData(
             GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             sizeof(points),
             points,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);

glVertexAttribPointer(
                      GLKVertexAttribPosition,
                      2,
                      GL_FLOAT,
                      GL_FALSE,
                      2*4,
                      NULL);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
```

Kindly help me out.

Edit:
**Problem**
Actually the problem is: I can't figure out what is the difference between:

```
GLfloat points[] =
{
    10.0f, 10.0f,
};
```

AND

```
GLfloat *points = (GLfloat*)malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * 2);
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    points[i] = 10.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bet will be that the problem is the `sizeof(points)` in the `glBufferData` data call: in this case it will return the size of the *pointer* which is a word i.e. 4 bytes (or something like this). You should pass the *real* size of your array that will be the same what you calculate in the `malloc` code.